# Using multiple CPU cores in Tensorflow probability

Tags: tensorflow, mcmc, tensorflow-probability

I am trying to sample using MCMC in Tensorflow probability, but it seems to utilize only one CPU core. Is it possible to use multiple CPUs parallelly?

Comment: I have myself not found a better way than manually setting the number of chains to a low value and starting many runs in parallel on my own - I am curious too though, if anyone knows!

Answer (score 0):

You can try playing with these two parameters:
[set_intra_op_parallelism_threads](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/threading/set_intra_op_parallelism_threads) and
[set_inter_op_parallelism_threads](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/threading/set_inter_op_parallelism_threads).

However, there supposedly automatically chosen:

> 0 means the system picks an appropriate number.

and setting a large number does not guarantee that all nodes will be used and neither does it guarantee that they will be used to a 100%.